# Why does my art's color display look different on my art program vs. on the internet (on the same monitor)?

Tags: color, images, monitor

When I'm working in an art program on my computer, be it Photoshop, FireAlpaca, or just the whiteboard app that came with the computer, the colors look fine. However, when I save the finished image and open it back up in the pictures app, the color appears a lot cooler and harsher than I wanted it to be (and in one piece, the golden yellow ended up turning into a really gross shade of light green). It also appears like this when posting it on the internet.

Interestingly enough, this even happens when taking screenshots of something already online and then posting those screenshots, so at this point I can't tell if it's something with my computer's web display or what.

Comment: You need to start reading about color profiles and color theory. This question is far, far, far too broad. -- A good place to start would be an internet search for the same topic. There's no reason users here should repeat what's been already written.. there's a MOUNTAIN of information out there regarding this issue.

Comment: Set your image to use sRGB as the colour profile.  Thats the colour profile used on the web.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by your color management engine, which is simply put configured wrong. Its fairly typical since odds are your display devices and your office space is unlikely to be calibrated and set up properly.

What does the color management engine do? It tries to show you colors as they were intended to be shown, but what has been told to the engine does not reflect your setup very well. See numbers are not colors, they are signals for specific devices. Each device shows a different color for same signal value. So inorder for us to agree what a specific color is we need to be able to convert between devices.

But you are on same device... Well yes but web is implicitly assumed to be sRGB. If your monitor is not, and your assumption is wrong then the color management engine will get lost because it does not know where the image originated from. Its a bit like trying to navigate with a map of New York in Paris its unlikely to make your results very consistent.

Now all of this is a few orders more complex than people expect to encounter so it is admittedly extremely hard to understand. Especially since the colormanagement engine has to also deal with things your monitor can not show.

Comment: And to add to that confusion, Chrome & Firefox both have colour management switched off by default.

Comment: @Tetsujin no my firefox has it turned on by default, though it used to have it disabled. It does howver not support v4 color management by default but that shouldnt be an issue. So its on but not as fully on as it could be.

Comment: Its defaults for mis-matched profiles is dodgy though. There was a question on here or photography about it - I'll try to find it later...

Comment: @Tetsujin i think they fixed that but didnt fix it for css. Anyway i agree that they should turn it completely on.

Comment: I found the QA - https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/124357/57929 - I haven't looked at FF since to see if they fixed it.